# Decrypt content from Confluence secure macro using gpg cli

Tags: gpg, confluence, secure

I am looking to know if the data encrypted with Confluence ''secure'' macro/module can be decrypted using cli as when I look more closely, I can clearly see that the macro use OpenPGP.js.

I should be able to use gpg to decrypt the data ? But how ?
BTW, the ''encryption'' phase is using LDAP user/pass at them of the ''secure'' info generation within Confluence.

Wondering if it is just a matter of the correct cli options to be able to decrypt the file or if there is a broad pub/sec key pair at Confluence level to top it off ?

Comment: Yeah.... Wel.... It seem the Confluence has it's own keypair to encrypt the date and it's in the database. It does not only use your userName/pass to protect the content.